# Multiple controls with the same ID 'cb1' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs

Tags: asp.net

I bind datatable values to gridview. I have added three templatefield column in aspx page for permenantly and I add two dynamic checkbox column by creating column using itemplate interface.everythings ok upto databind.but i want to bind checkbox value from datatable value. if datatable value is true , then checkbox value is checked. For that i tried following code.

```
DataTable bindclassattendance = inter.getstudentattendresult(comp);

Createcolumn();

if (bindclassattendance.Rows.Count>0 )
{
Classattendancegrid.DataSource = bindclassattendance;
    Classattendancegrid.DataBind();

    for (int i = 0; i < bindclassattendance.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        bool check1 = Convert.ToBoolean(bindclassattendance.Rows[i]["AM"].ToString());
        if (check1)
        {
            CheckBox chk = Classattendancegrid.Rows[i].FindControl("AM") as CheckBox;
            chk.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            CheckBox chk = Classattendancegrid.Rows[i].FindControl("AM") as CheckBox;
            chk.Checked = false;
        }
        bool check2 = Convert.ToBoolean(bindclassattendance.Rows[i]["PM"].ToString());
        if (check2)
        {
            CheckBox chk = Classattendancegrid.Rows[i].FindControl("PM") as CheckBox;
            chk.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            CheckBox chk = Classattendancegrid.Rows[i].FindControl("PM") as CheckBox;
            chk.Checked = false;
        }

    }
```

And dynamic column `Createcolumn()` is:

```
private void Createcolumn()
{
    TemplateField amtemp = new TemplateField();
    amtemp.ShowHeader = true;
    amtemp.HeaderText = "AM";
    amtemp.ItemTemplate = new gridviewtemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, "AM", "AM", "CheckBox");
    Classattendancegrid.Columns.Add(amtemp);

    TemplateField pmtemp = new TemplateField();
    pmtemp.ShowHeader = true;
    pmtemp.HeaderText = "PM";
    pmtemp.ItemTemplate = new gridviewtemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, "PM", "PM", "CheckBox");
    Classattendancegrid.Columns.Add(pmtemp);
}
```

and the above error is occured. how can solve it and i never used any name as 'cb1'. That error occured in line following line

```
CheckBox chk = Classattendancegrid.Rows[i].FindControl("AM") as CheckBox;
```

and my aspx page is

```
<asp:GridView ID="Classattendancegrid" runat="server" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdatabound="Classattendancegrid_RowDataBound" 
              style="margin-left: 184px; margin-top: 27px">
  <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AdmissionNumber">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lbladmissionnumber" runat="server" 
                  Text='<%#Eval("AdmissionNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RollNumber">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblrollno" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Rollnumber") %>'></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="StudentName">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblStudentName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
</column>
</asp:GridView)
```

Comment: Show your GridView markup also

Comment: I edited  my question with markup.

Comment: Ok. your GridView seems fine. Then possibly issue is in your InstantiateIn method. check the same and if possible show us too for checking also